# Set dynamic value for attribute's default value in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have 2 attributes, "account" and "newContact", I want to set the default value for Account.Name for "newContact" as the value of "account" attribute, i.e. whatever will be the value of account attribute that must be assigned to Account.Name in "newContact" attribute. Can someone please help !

```
<aura:attribute name="account" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact" 
                default="{'sObjectType':'Contact', 'FirstName':'', 
                           'LastName':'', 'Account.Name':'', 
                           'Birthdate':''}"/>
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: what you have write so far? Please Share it.

Comment: In your component component and helper you can perform `get` or `set` any attribute. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: My parent component is setting the value for "account" attribute and on the basis of this value I want to set AccountName for my "newContact" attribute. I am not able to use "{!v.account}" inside default.

Comment: Here the type should be `sobjectType` not `sObjectType` it's case sensitive;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mistake you made in the Attribute Decleration of "newContact" attribute.You cannot set the the default value of Contact of Account.Name directly as a String.You should set the Account of Contact as an Object and then you can set the "account" attribute value for "newContact" like this.

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="account" type="string" default="abc"/>
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact" 
            default="{'sObjectType':'Contact', 'FirstName':'', 
                       'LastName':'', 'Account':{Id:'',Name:''}, 
                       'Birthdate':''}"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
```

Controller:

```
({
    init: function(component,event,helper){

        var contact = component.get('v.newContact');
        contact.Account.Name = component.get('v.account');
        component.set('v.contact', contact);
        console.log(component.get('v.newContact'));
    }
)}
```